# How to "sleep" a Windows 8 laptop without closing the lid

Tags: windows-8, laptop, sleep, dell-xps

I have a Dell XPS Windows 8 laptop.

I'd like to be able to "sleep" it overnight without needing to close the lid (often it is on a laptop stand where closing it is awkward).

The "Power" menu has just "shut down" and "restart".
My keyboard does not have a "sleep" button.

How can I invoke the "sleep" function?

Thanks

Comment: Sleep could also be disabled in the bios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the control panel item Power, and "Choose what the power buttons do"

Change the power button to Sleep. You can still shut down the computer from the start menu.

Comment: Those dropdowns are rather strange on my machine. All four of them are blank. If I open the dropdown, "sleep" does not appear as an option, only "Do Nothing", "Hibernate" or "Shut down". Currently, when I close the lid, the machine does sleep (or perhaps it hibernates and is really really quick). There may be domain policies affecting this machine -- it's on a Windows domain.

Comment: a domain policy may be configured to prevent sleep states. Try sysinternals psshutdown with the -d switch

Comment: I think sleep is disabled on this machine by domain policy. Pressing the power button does seem to hibernate the machine, so I'll make do with that.